# Type-C suddenly stop working on Debian

Tags: linux, debian, hdmi, external-display, usb-3.1-type-c

I have an HP Pavilion Power 15-CB030NL with Debian 10, kernel 4.19.0-9-amd64.

Following are my 2 GPUs:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 630 (rev 04) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company HD Graphics 630
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 133
    Memory at b2000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Memory at c0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    I/O ports at 5000 [size=64]
    [virtual] Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: [40] Vendor Specific Information: Len=0c <?>
    Capabilities: [70] Express Root Complex Integrated Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [ac] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [d0] Power Management version 2
    Capabilities: [100] Process Address Space ID (PASID)
    Capabilities: [200] Address Translation Service (ATS)
    Capabilities: [300] Page Request Interface (PRI)
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915

01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Mobile] (rev ff) (prog-if ff)
    !!! Unknown header type 7f
    Kernel modules: nvidia
```

I never figured out how to make the HDMI works on this laptop even instaling the nvidia driver and using bumblebee to switch between the integrated intel and the dedicated nvidia.
However, I started using the type-c port (with an hdmi adapter) and everything has been working fine. Suddenly one day when I was using the laptop with an external monitor, it turns black and the type-c port stopped working too!

I'll paste here some interesting outputs:

## lshw | grep -A10 -i usb

```
      capabilities: pci upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect edd int13floppynec int13floppytoshiba int13floppy360 int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int9keyboard int10video acpi usb biosbootspecification uefi
 *-cpu
      description: CPU
      product: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7700HQ CPU @ 2.80GHz
      vendor: Intel Corp.
      physical id: 4
      bus info: cpu@0
      version: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7700HQ CPU @ 2.80GHz
      serial: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
      slot: U3E1
      size: 3339MHz
    *-usb
         description: USB controller
         product: Sunrise Point-H USB 3.0 xHCI Controller
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 14
         bus info: pci@0000:00:14.0
         version: 31
         width: 64 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: pm msi xhci bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=xhci_hcd latency=0
         resources: irq:132 memory:b4500000-b450ffff
       *-usbhost:0
            product: xHCI Host Controller
            vendor: Linux 4.19.0-9-amd64 xhci-hcd
            physical id: 0
            bus info: usb@1
            logical name: usb1
            version: 4.19
            capabilities: usb-2.00
            configuration: driver=hub slots=16 speed=480Mbit/s
          *-usb:0
               description: Keyboard
               product: USB Keyboard
               vendor: Logitech
               physical id: 2
               bus info: usb@1:2
               version: 79.00
               capabilities: usb-1.10
               configuration: driver=usbhid maxpower=98mA speed=1Mbit/s
          *-usb:1
               description: Mouse
               product: USB Optical Mouse
               vendor: Logitech
               physical id: 3
               bus info: usb@1:3
               version: 72.00
               capabilities: usb-2.00
               configuration: driver=usbhid maxpower=100mA speed=1Mbit/s
          *-usb:2
               description: Video
               product: HP Wide Vision HD Camera
               vendor: Chicony
               physical id: 4
               bus info: usb@1:4
               version: 32.22
               capabilities: usb-2.00
               configuration: driver=uvcvideo maxpower=500mA speed=480Mbit/s
          *-usb:3
               description: Bluetooth wireless interface
               vendor: Intel Corp.
               physical id: 7
               bus info: usb@1:7
               version: 0.03
               capabilities: bluetooth usb-2.00
               configuration: driver=btusb maxpower=100mA speed=12Mbit/s
       *-usbhost:1
            product: xHCI Host Controller
            vendor: Linux 4.19.0-9-amd64 xhci-hcd
            physical id: 1
            bus info: usb@2
            logical name: usb2
            version: 4.19
            capabilities: usb-3.00
            configuration: driver=hub slots=8 speed=5000Mbit/s
    *-generic:1
         description: Signal processing controller
         product: Sunrise Point-H Thermal subsystem
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 14.2
         bus info: pci@0000:00:14.2
         version: 31
         width: 64 bits
         clock: 33MHz
```

--

On # tail -f /var/log/kern.log nothing happens if I insert or remove anything from the type-c port.

## lsusb

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 8087:0a2a Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 04f2:b5d6 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 046d:c077 Logitech, Inc. M105 Optical Mouse
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 046d:c326 Logitech, Inc. Washable Keyboard K310
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

## cat /boot/config-4.19.0-8-amd64 | grep TYPEC

```
CONFIG_TYPEC=m
CONFIG_TYPEC_TCPM=m
# CONFIG_TYPEC_TCPCI is not set
# CONFIG_TYPEC_RT1711H is not set
CONFIG_TYPEC_FUSB302=m
CONFIG_TYPEC_UCSI=m
CONFIG_TYPEC_TPS6598X=m
# CONFIG_TYPEC_MUX_PI3USB30532 is not set
# CONFIG_TYPEC_DP_ALTMODE is not set
```

I was using also an external Asus ZenScreen MB16ACM monitor and it was working fine (so just using the type-c to type-c cable without any adapter). Now the power light turns on when I connect it to the laptop, but it doens't "see" it. I also tried a type-c to usb adapter (with a simple usb external driver) and again, it's not detected by debian at all.

I'm wondering if the CONFIG_TYPEC_DP_ALTMODE should be enabled in the kernel (CONFIG_TYPEC_DP_ALTMODE=m) but I didn't figured out how to do it.

## UPDATE

I found out that the type-c port stops working if I turn on the webcam or if I virtualize with VMWare. It happens after a while, like 10-15 minutes. I start thinking it's related to a "power-saving" issue, but I deactivated all settings about the power saving, and the power cable is always on. So the pc isn't under its battery either.

Comment: Have you tried using the FN key along with the key which looks like a monitor. From a book online from HP.com (.pdf) _Switches the screen image between display devices connected to the system. __For example__, if a monitor is connected to the computer, repeatedly pressing this key alternates the screen image from the computer display to the monitor display to __a simultaneous display on both the computer and the monitor.__ That is using an HDMI to HDMI also.

Comment: I already did it but nothing changed. Actually now it suddenly started working again! I don't understand what happened, just hope it won't happend again. Even if the HDMI still doesn't work, but at least the type-c is doing its job now..

Comment: I'm glad, at least, it started working again, thanks for the update. May be you should look for a BIOS update, or maybe there is something wrong with the HDMI port? That machine came with Windows 10 64-bit if I remember correctly, have you tried using it in Windows, the HDMI? Good luck.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm here again. Suddendly the type-c port stopped working. anybody any idea?

Comment: I quick way to solve the problem is to switch off the laptop, remove all usb and cables, keep the power button pressed for 30 seconds. Then switch on the pc again and the type-c is working fine again. This doesn't solve the problem in general, but it's an useful quick-fix